# Content search in Sitecore pointing to custom index instead of Master

Tags: solr, content-search

we have configured **SOLR MASTER/SALVE** in our environment on different servers and Configured the required replication. Index is rebuild and web site is search is working. when we try to search with in Content tree, it gives message as "No Result Found". While checking the search log file, got below entries. It is searching on custom index **sitecore_community_index** instead of default **Master index**

> 6652 10:17:27 INFO  Serialized Query -
>   ?q=_name:(_url)&rows=1&fq=_templatename:("Template
>   field")&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_community_index) 6652 10:17:27 INFO 
>   Search Query : (((((-_group:(154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901)  *:*)
>   AND (_path:(154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901) AND
>   _latestversion:(True))) AND _path:(154d56cc0de243c7bbc0a25bd7ffd901)) AND _latestversion:(1)) AND _datasource:(sitecore)) 6652 10:17:27 INFO
>   Search Index : sitecore_community_index 6652 10:17:27 INFO  Search
>   Took : 11ms 5708 10:18:29 INFO  Query - (_name:("Mail server*") OR
>   (_content:("*Mail server*") AND _language:(en))) 5708 10:18:29 INFO 
>   Serialized Query - ?q=(_name:("Mail server*") OR (_content:("*Mail
>   server*") AND
>   _language:(en)))&rows=2147483647&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_community_index)

Comment: can you share C# code that call search API?

Comment: Here is a detailed explanation how Sitecore determines which index should be used: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/9799/277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore content search might select the first index matching the context database. You have to ensure your `sitecore_community_index` is defined after the standard `sitecore_master_index`. You likely patched your index before the default ones with `patch:before` or because your patch file name is alphabetically lower than the out of the box Solr configuration files.

Comment: Thanks for response. I do not have any  file with patch in my environment. Please suggest if need to create one to use. Also where I have to check defined order of index

Comment: The index order can be found by opening the Sitecore Indexing Manager from the Sitecore Control Panel. An alternative would be to open the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page and check the order of the `<index>` elements in the `<indexes>` element.

Comment: You mentioned having no configuration patch file for your custom index. In that case, in which file have you added your index definition to? It is always recommended not to modify the out of the box Sitecore configuration files and always use additional patch files to add or modify the configuration. That way, Sitecore upgrades are easier as the base files are not modified.

Comment: Let me add here, I am fairly new to Search and SOLR so have very limited knowledge and hence, request can you please help with name of the default files and process to add the additional patch file to add and modify the configuration

Comment: If you have successful queries targeting the `sitecore_community_index`, it means it already exists in a configuration file under `\App_Config\Include`. You just have to find in which one it is. Looking at the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page would tell you in which file it is in the `patch:source` attribute value of the `<index name="sitecore_community_index" ...>` element.

Comment: There is very strange behaviour I had noticed post checking and updating few things. If I search using Item ID, I get the search result and post that, if any key word is used to search, it is showing the search results. However, if we navigate to any other page and come back to check without Item ID, search again yields no match found.

Comment: I fear that this new issue is completely related to how website search was implemented (code) in your solution and that I cannot really help with it. Is your sitecore_community_index vs default master index problem resolved? Then it would be good to accept an answer. For any additional question you have, it is better to create completely separate posts. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is not resolved yet and struggling to get it resolved. Tried re configuring as well but yet no solution. Not sure why this issue cropped after configuring Salve/Master and replication.

Comment: My Issue is resolved by editing the web index file. Post that modify settings as per your suggestion and issue is closed. Thanks