# Use site specific search indexes configured on SXA site item in Content Search API

Tags: sxa, content-search

When making Content Search API calls, Sitecore resolves the index based on certain logic which is very well explained [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/9799/1003).

In SXA, we do have an option to configure the indexes on the site item, like below.

[image]

In Content Search API, is it possible to resolve to these indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SXA, we have custom service called `IndexResolver` which we are using to resolve proper index (including site indexes if such are defined). It has the following priorities while resolving index:

1. It will first, check if there are any language-specific indexes defined in the site, e.g.: `master/en`
2. Then, it will check if there are any database indexes defined in the site, e.g.: `web/*`
3. If there are no site-related indexes the logic will try to get default SXA index `sitecore_sxa_master_index` or `sitecore_sxa_web_index`
4. If default SXA indexes won't be found, it will fallback to Sitecore logic and call `ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(rootItem)`

You can inject the `IndexResolver` using standard constructor injection or by using `ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IIndexResolver>()` and use it like this:

```
ISearchIndex searchIndex = IndexResolver.ResolveIndex(contextItem);
IProviderSearchContext search = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext();
```

Comment: Thanks Dawid, you are the saver.